# How to make an iPad like commercial video?

Tags: after-effects

We're looking to make an [iPad like commercial](http://www.apple.com/ipad/) video for one of our apps.

My Question is, what technologies are involved in making this kind of a video? Is it `flash`/`after effects`? or something else all together.

Also, if there is a tutorial which can help me build something like this video, it'd be helpful. cheers.

Comment: 'I am a mac' ads were very easy to reproduce: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=av6fWfmugds

Answer (score 4):

A lot of commercials involving electronic devices, like Apple advertisements, usually have simulated screens. This is usually done in After Effects or 3D software like 3ds Max or Cinema 4D.

You can do this animation and screen replacement yourself if you have the software and knowledge required. If you are an After Effects or 3D beginner, there are tutorials that can help you and ready-made project files you can download and add your app's footage to.

Example Commercial:

- 
Download Commercial Template: http://videohive.net/item/tablet-commercial/166585

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.